# I keep getting "Not all code paths return a value" error message

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a string function, but when I start to implement code it's yelling at me at the first line of code.

I've tried to just implement `public static string IsUniqueChar(string str)`,
`public string IsUniqueChar(string str)`, both of these throw an error. I know it's something small but I can't figure it out.

```cs
public static string IsUniqueChar(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int val = str.ElementAt(i) - 'a';
    }
}
```

`IsUniqueChar` is underlined in red saying that "not all code paths return a value".

Comment: You need to `return` a `string`. Or change the function return type to `void`.

Comment: First of all, `IsUniqueChar` seems like a function that needs to return a `bool`, not a `string`. Second, regardless of the return type, you _must_ make sure that the function returns an object/value of that type to get rid of this compiler error. Please note that methods that don't return anything should have a `void` return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare your method like a method returning a value of type `string`, but it doesn't return anything.. Try adding a `return` statement to it:

```cs
public static string IsUniqueChar(string str)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
    {
        int val = str.ElementAt(i) - 'a';

    }
    return "hello";
}
```